# Why do I have duplicate files with ~Stashed changes and ~Updated upstream postfix

Tags: git, pycharm

Why do I have duplicate files that exist. I have index.js file and there are two other files named "index.js~Stashed changes" and "index.js~Updated upstream".

How to removed these files?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is because your index.js should have some changes

Try this :

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/index.js
```

Or, Check your index.js and pick required portion

Comment: The file is still there.

Comment: Can you add some snapshots and content of index.js

Comment: I've added the screenshot.